# Support landscape orientation in one page universal app wp8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

If I set the supported orientations to both portrait and landscape in `Package.appxmanifest` file, the default behaviour on WP8.1 the layout automatically changes when I move my device (rotate the emulator).

I want to enable this behaviour on a per-page basis (or, alternatively, suppress it for some pages).

I tried using this RT example - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263110.aspx - 'How to stop using LayoutAwarePage':

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    this.Loaded += PageLoaded;
    this.Unloaded += PageUnloaded;
 }

 private void PageUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Window.Current.SizeChanged -= Window_SizeChanged;
 }

 private void PageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Window.Current.SizeChanged += Window_SizeChanged;
 }

 private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
 {
 // layout my ui
 }
```

However, the Window_SizeChanged is never called, regardless of whether I add the resolutions to the manifest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I should've been more thorough in my googling. To do this at runtime:

```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
      Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait
                                                                            | DisplayOrientations.Landscape
                                                                            | DisplayOrientations.PortraitFlipped;
    }
```

and then to cancel the effects

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
      Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;
    }
```